# SearchView shows Data.entity.Cantact.@85c7ce6 in Android Studio

Tags: database, android-studio, search, android-room, searchview

In this project that I did, the search view works properly, but as you can see in the picture, the output is like this:

output: com.mahdi.roomdatabase.Data.entity.Cantact.@85c7ce6

what's wrong with this codes?

[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMqfB.png)

```
    Codes:


    Observer<DatabaseNew> observer = new Observer<DatabaseNew>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(DatabaseNew databaseNew) {


            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    getDatabasefromDb(query);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    getDatabasefromDb(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
    };
    mainModel.getLiveData().observe(this, observer);
}


private void getDatabasefromDb(String searchText) {
    searchText = "%" + searchText + "%";
    contacts=databaseNew.getDatabaseInfo(SearchActivity.this, searchText);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.
            simple_list_item_1, contacts);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

---

```
public List<Contact> getDatabaseInfo(Context context, String Query) {
    return getContactDAO(context).getContactList(Query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's wrong with this codes?

The adapter is using the default `toString` method of the Cantact class.

Consider the following.

A class called **School** is :-

```
@Entity(
        indices = {
                @Index(value = "schoolName", unique = true)
        }
)
class School {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long schoolId=null;
    String schoolName;

    School(){}
    @Ignore
    School(String schoolName) {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }
    School(Long schoolId, String schoolName) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }
}
```

The the following code:-

```
School school = new School("The School");
Log.d("EXAMPLE","School if you use the default toString method is " + school + " Whilst getting the value (the name) is " + school.schoolName);
```

results in :-

```
D/EXAMPLE: School if you use the default toString method is a.a.so73431456javaroomcatchtryexample.School@f6edce8 Whilst getting the value (the name) is The School
```

i.e. the School class's default toString method prints details about the instance of the School object.

However, if the School class is changed to include :-

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID=" + this.schoolId + "; SCHOOLNAME=" + this.schoolName;
}
```

Then the result is

```
D/EXAMPLE: School if you use the default toString method is ID=null; SCHOOLNAME=The School Whilst getting the value (the name) is The School
```

You need to either

1. pass the actual values, as strings, you want displayed to the adpater,
2. use a customised adapter to extract the values that you want displayed,
3. or override the Cantacts `toString` method to return the String that you want to be displayed.

   - noting that 3 is probably the least preferable, albeit the simplest.

Comment: i really thank you, your answer exactly helped me for solving this problem 
I could solve this problem by adding this toString() method to the contact class